# Как напечатать стек вызовов в обработчике исключения?

Tags: c++, windows

У меня есть c++ программа на Windows, в которой я хочу предусмотреть полный логгинг стека вызовов в случае возникновения ошибки (hardware, software). Возможно ли реализовать такую функциональность? Вот небольшой кусок кода, содержащий внешний seh обработчик:

```
__try
{
     difficult_task();
}
__except(my_seh_filter(GetExceptionInformation()))
{
    // How to print full backtrace of exception here?
}
```

Что я знаю на данный момент:

1. Поставляемая windows DbgHelp.dll позволяет получить информацию о стэке вызовов (распечатать стэк можно).
2. SEH обработка исключений позволяет получить контекст в котором возникло исключение. (Тип исключения, адресс возникновения исключения, регистры процессора на момент выброса исключения).

Есть одно **НО**. Я хочу распечатать стек вызовов непосредственно в seh фильтре или соответсвующем catch блоке. И мне не совсем понятно, как можно используя эти два инструмента  распечатать backtrace (он ведь на момент раскрутки стэка может изменится). Одно дело когда я распечатываю стэк в момент выброса исключения. Другое когда в момент обработки (я предполагаю что на момент обработки исключения полной информации о стеке у меня уже не будет).

Comment: возможно это будет полезно https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22467604/8674428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стек вызовов проще всего вывести из SEH-фильтра, передавая в функцию *StackWalk64* указатель на контекст, возвращенный *GetExceptionInformation*. Как-то так:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "DbgHelp.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

const int MaxNameLen = 256;

//выводит стек вызовов, соответствующий указанному контексту
void printStack( CONTEXT* ctx )
{
    BOOL    result;
    HANDLE  process;
    HANDLE  thread;
    HMODULE hModule;
            
    STACKFRAME64        stack;
    ULONG               frame;    
    DWORD64             displacement;

    char buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];
    char name[ MaxNameLen ];
    char module[MaxNameLen];
    PSYMBOL_INFO pSymbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;

    // StackWalk64 модифицирует контекст в 64-битных приложениях,
    // что может привести к падению. Для предотвращения этого  
    // создадим копию контекста.
    CONTEXT ctxCopy;
    memcpy(&ctxCopy, ctx, sizeof(CONTEXT));
    
    memset( &stack, 0, sizeof( STACKFRAME64 ) );

    process                = GetCurrentProcess();
    thread                 = GetCurrentThread();
    displacement           = 0;
#if !defined(_M_AMD64)
    stack.AddrPC.Offset    = (*ctx).Eip;
    stack.AddrPC.Mode      = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrStack.Offset = (*ctx).Esp;
    stack.AddrStack.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
    stack.AddrFrame.Offset = (*ctx).Ebp;
    stack.AddrFrame.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
#endif

    SymInitialize( process, NULL, TRUE ); //загружаем символы

    for( frame = 0; ; frame++ )
    {
        //получаем следующий вызов из стека
        result = StackWalk64
        (
#if defined(_M_AMD64)
            IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64
#else
            IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386
#endif
            ,
            process,
            thread,
            &stack,
            &ctxCopy,
            NULL,
            SymFunctionTableAccess64,
            SymGetModuleBase64,
            NULL
        );

        if( !result ) break;        

        //полчаем имя символа для адреса
        pSymbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        pSymbol->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;
        SymFromAddr(process, ( ULONG64 )stack.AddrPC.Offset, &displacement, pSymbol);
                
        hModule = NULL;
        lstrcpyA(module,"");        
        GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS | GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, 
            (LPCTSTR)(stack.AddrPC.Offset), &hModule);

        //получаем имя модуля
        if(hModule != NULL)GetModuleFileNameA(hModule,module,MaxNameLen);       

        printf ("%lu: %s  (in %s)\n",frame,pSymbol->Name,module);       
                
    }
}



void BuggedFunction()
{
    int * p = NULL;
    *p = 5;
}

void bar()
{
    BuggedFunction();
}

void foo()
{    
     bar();    
}

int seh_filter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex)
{
    printf("Exception 0x%x occured\n",ex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode);  
    printStack(ex->ContextRecord);
    
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Russian");
    
    __try
    {
        foo();
    }
    __except(seh_filter(GetExceptionInformation()))
    {       
        printf("Exception \n");         
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, в принципе в итоге так я и сделал. Единственный минус данного подхода в различии получаемых стэков (см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/790419/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-x86-%D0%B8-x64 и https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48985041/different-seh-filtering-in-x86-and-x64) Если коротко, то реализация seh обработки была изменена в x64 версии windows