# Различие в стеках вызовов на x86 и x64

Tags: c++, windows, исключения

Я реализовываю логирование информации о выброшенных исключениях (информация включает в себя стэк вызовов). Я спрашивал недавно как можно реализовать логирование стэка вызовов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924449/reliable-way-to-print-exception-backtrace-in-catch-handler. И решил проверить стэки на платформах x86 и x64. Результаты сравнения немного удивили меня. Вот программа:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
};

void foo3()
{
    throw A();
}

void foo2()
{
    foo3(); 
}

void foo1()
{
    foo2();
}

void foo()
{
    try
    {
        foo1();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "exception rethrowing" << endl;
        throw;
    }
}
int seh_filter(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS* exception)
{
    cout << "SEH FILTER" << endl;
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

int main(void)
{
    __try
    {
        foo();
    }
    __except(seh_filter(GetExceptionInformation()))
    {
        cout << "SEH catch handler" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Установил точку остановки в `seh_filter` чтобы просмотреть стэк (запустил дебажные сборки). Вот изображения:

[image]
Не могу понять, почему так сильно различаются стэки (особенно под x64). Я только слышал что изменилась обработка seh исключений под x64. Использую msvc2013 под Windows 10.

Comment: А это x86 или WOW64?

Comment: @VTT, я собираю и запускаю программу на 64 битной Windows, если вы об этом? Насколько я понимаю Wow64 - это просто поддержка запуска x86 приложений на 64 битной Windows

Comment: Я это к тому, что стек на нативном x86 может также отличаться от WOW64.

Comment: @VTT, это хорошее замечание, не задумывался об этом. К сожалению пока нет возможности это проверить, хотя так оно и есть думаю.

Comment: Могу предположить, что x64 и x86 немного по разному скомпилировали обработку исключения. Вот то что от `foo()` до `foo3()` идет, то имее смысл, а до и после может быть что угодно. Больше чем уверен, что если наполнить foo1,2,3() какимто кодом, то цепочка `foo()->foo1()->foo2()->foo3()` будет сохранятся. *UPD* В релизе может быть вообще что угодно.

Comment: @ffk, в том то и проблема что нет. Это очень сильно упрощенная программа, такое поведение воспроизводится и на более сложном коде. А вот что обработка seh исключений разная - это 100%. В x86 используется frame-based подход, в x64 table-based, но почему такое различие в стэках я не знаю

Comment: Хороши, стеки очень похожи, местами немного разные, а проблема в чём? это нельзя учесть? это чему-то мешает?

Comment: @nick_n_a, я бы не сказал что прям немного. На картинке с callstack'ами это отчетливо видно. Небольшая цепочка стэк фреймов просто отсутствует, как это учесть и восстановить - непонятно.

Comment: Если вы знаете что такое стек вызовов, как найти стековое окно, как найти точку вызова, и начало ф-ции с которой произошёл вызов - тогда эту цепочку можно поднять. Но не для всех EIP/rIP есть имена, microsoft и многи другие любят безимянные ф-ции, вот как в kernel xxxx1fe4. Если вам нужно, можно найти этот адрес в IDA pro, и выкопать цепочку. Но практического смысла я в этом не вижу. Разве что вы замахнулись на свою OS, виртуалку или антивирус.

Comment: Пока могу сказать что есть "ненужный" верх, который сложновато, но можно отфильтровать, и есть "дно", ниже которого нет смысла копать -  `_main()`. Ещё можно поднять Debug-окно call-stack и используя dump посмотреть, мне кажется call-stack окно даёт более детально стек вызовов (но не везде)

Comment: Алгоритм поиска примерно такой, для 32 бита, берем stack-dump и идем к дну стека. Под каждым значением проверяеи есть ли код, если есть - то присутствует ли там команда call - если да - то это и есть адрес куда был вызов. Из адреса по таблице экспорта (если это dll можно найти имя, если адрес "свой" - то нужно декодировать debug-info, если имя не найдено - то никак его не получить). это "очень грубо", потому что есть ещё много тонкостей. Как распределено адресное пространство между dll можно посмотреть... в process-exporer (sysinternal) или в окне debug-modules (если в вашей среде оно есть)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В MSVC С++ исключения реализованы на базе структурированной обработки исключений  (structure exception handling - SEH).

Сама по себе реализация SEH на x86 и x64 отличается радикально.

x86 SEH использует машинные инструкции для формирования стека обработчиков исключений по ходу выполнения программы, стек вызовов содержит ссылки на обработчики.

x64 содержит метаданные для обработки исключений в отдельный области исполнимого файла (`IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION`). А для кода, сгенерированного в процессе выполнения программы, есть API для дополнения этих метаданных - см [RtlAddFunctionTable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-rtladdfunctiontable).

Так, x64 подход и эффективнее (по производительности в случае отсутствия исключений), и безопаснее - меньше возможности подменить стек обработчиков исключений у злоумышленников.

От x86 подхода, при этом, не отказались, видимо, из-за обратной совместимости -- уже скомпилированные программы содержат "старый" подход к обработке исключений. (Для снижения риска подмены стека обработчиков исключений используется SAFESEH - опциональная метаинформация об обработчиках, которая проверяется перед раскруткой, если она есть)

---

Это всё было про "системную" часть стека.

О разнице `foo1`/`foo2`/`foo3` сложно судить не зная опция компилятора.
Влияющие факторы:

- компилятор может воспользоваться тем, что функции никогда не взовращают управление, а только бросают исключение, а может не воспользоваться
- оптимизация хвостового вызова может быть применена, а может и не быть
- встраивание (inlining) может быть применено, а может не быть (при встраивании фунций нет в аппаратном стеке вызовов, но отладчик может всё же суметь показать "встроенный  фрейм" при наличии соотвествующей отладочной информации)

Конкретнее можно сказать по дизассемблу программы.