# Возможно ли получить список стектрейсов функции вплоть до мейна с++

Tags: c++

Я бы хотел узнать все пути вызова функции начиная с самого верхнего уровня(c main), возможно ли их получить? Мб есть какая то утилита или что то типа того

Comment: Ну как вариант, вставить в функцию вывод стека в лог как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809888/240512 , позапускать программу, и посмотреть, что записалось в лог

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Visual Studio в контекстном меню для функции есть пункт View Call Hierarchy.

В Clion в меню Navigate есть пункт Call Hierarchy. По моему опыту обычно не работает.

Comment: а в clion есть что то подобное?

Comment: @DenverToha Обновил ответ.